# cookieSession not a function

Tags: javascript, function, express, session, session-cookies

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var passport = require('passport');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var cookieSession = ('cookie-session');
var passportSetup = require('./config/passport-setup');
var keys = require('./config/keys');

mongoose.connect(keys.mongodb.db, () => {
console.log('Connected to mongodb');
})

var app = express();

//View Engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.use(cookieSession({
maxAge: 86400000, //milliseconds
keys: [keys.session.cookieKey]
}));

//init passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

I am trying to get cookie-sessions to work with my project but I am running into an issue. The terminal outputs this.

```
app.use(cookieSession({
TypeError: cookieSession is not a function
```

Any help would be much appreicated!

Comment: Cookie session won't work unless you have these 3 in order.
`app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.cookieSession());
app.use(app.router);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `require` in front of `cookie-session`

```
var cookieSession = ('cookie-session');
```

should be

```
var cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
```

Othen than that, it looks fine.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was just super tired and must have missed it. Thanks again it worked :)